# How to create a distance between the geom text and the bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a following problem. I want increase a padding bettween the text and the bar. But at same time, the value of text must be in the box of ggplot2 device.

Reproducible examples:

```
diamonds %>% 
  group_by(color) %>% 
  count() %>%
    ggplot(aes(color, y = n)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
      geom_text(
        aes(label = n), 
            vjust = 0.5, 
            hjust = "inward") +
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: You can play around with `nudge_y` value. Use `ifelse` if needed

Comment: nudge_y, in geom_text? please help me, i can t control, the inside and outside on the bar at same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you flipped coordinates it looks like your `hjust` and `vjust` calls were applied incorrectly. With this in mind, I only adjusted the text horizontally and I expanded the limits to fit the label for G, which would otherwise be cut off by the limits of the graph.

```
diamonds %>% 
    group_by(color) %>% 
    count() %>%
    ggplot(aes(color, y = n)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    geom_text(aes(label = n), 
    hjust = -.5) +
    coord_flip() + 
    expand_limits(y = 12000)
```

[image]

Or, if you want the text labels to be within the bars you can use the following.

```
diamonds %>% 
    group_by(color) %>% 
    count() %>%
    ggplot(aes(color, y = n)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    geom_text(aes(label = n), 
    hjust = 1.5) +
    coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: it is possible, put after bar, but dont use ```expand_limits(y = 12000)```

Comment: I don't understand what your last comment means. With ggplot's default scale, the text size would have to be very small.

Comment: but i have  this problem, some part of text is after and some part before. How to control at the same time, putting a padding

Comment: it not possible create a margin with hjust = "inward"